# How to find and replace text not followed by specific characters in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Say I have a bunch of files in which I want to replace

`class_a` by `class_b`

But I want needles followed by numeric characters to be ignored. Like `class_a2` should be ignored. What would be an appropriate regex?

More specifically this is in Actionscript 3 code.

---

*Backstory*: I have a decent sized Actionscript 3 code base containing a couple thousand source files and over million lines of code. FlashDevelop refactoring keeps freezing. Trying to find a workaround with minimal errors. Figured regex would be the easiest. Other (potential) solutions are welcome too!

Comment: Maybe adding `\b` to your regex would already be enough.

Comment: take a look at the utility   sed

Comment: What about `class_ab`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: "\bclass_[a-z]\b". Like trincot suggested.